# How many tables in mysql data base phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In previous versions of phpmyadmin was possible to see how many tables in every database you have. Example:

- database_xyz (36)
- database_xyz2 (125)
- wpress_test1 (12)
- wpress_test2 (14)

.. and so on...

In new versions you cannot see this information next to database name, how to enable this feature ?